# GeoNames - Retrieve radius of given location?

Tags: geonames

Is there a JSON web service available that can return the radius supplied from a given search term?

I sometimes see distance in web service response objects but this is always set to 0.

Ultimately I would like to know the radius of the given place name in order to perform a search which requires a radius parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation into the API it is my understanding that this is currently not supported.